# Speedbar opens a normal text buffer, not dired like

Tags: speedbar

I'm trying to use Speed bar when coding C++. My problem is, when I type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `speedbar` it opens an already opened code file instead.

Here you can see the effect:

[image]

Comment: What is your `M-x emacs-version`? Can you reproduce the effect with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: What @Tobias said: `emacs -Q`. Bisect your init file to find the culprit.